# Why does Java OutputStream write not write anything to stream

Tags: java, jsf, outputstream

I'm trying to solve this issue for a long time. I am trying to download a zip file by using JSF, this is why I use OutputStream. But write method does not work at all, it does not write anything to stream. Here's my code:

```
public void export() {
    ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = null;

    try {
        buffer = exportData(); // get ByteArrayOutputStream from method, it DOES write data to buffer

        final FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        final ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();

        externalContext.responseReset();
        externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=filename.zip");
        externalContext.setResponseContentType("application/octet-stream");

        OutputStream out = null;

        try {
            out = new BufferedOutputStream(externalContext.getResponseOutputStream());
            out.write(buffer.toByteArray()); // here it DOES NOT write anything to out, its length stays at 0
        } catch(Exception e) {
            // log error
        } finally {
            IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
        }

        facesContext.responseComplete();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        // log error
    } finally {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(buffer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe `buffer.toByteArray()` is returning a zero length `byte[]`?  Or a `byte[]` that doesn't containing any printable characters (so that it *looks* like it is writing nothing, but actually is.)

Comment: You should replace the `try ... `finally { closeQuietly(...); }` stuff with a *try with resources* statement; see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: Are the "log error" comments actually comments in your code, or is the logging just omitted for posting here?   If the former, then that can explain why you can't tell what's happening.

Comment: the comments are just omitted logging statements. I checked logs, there are no errors

Comment: "get ByteArrayOutputStream from method" -- But does it have any contents? Have you filled its content?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but… you can improve your application’s performance significantly by removing all uses of ByteArrayOutputStream and changing your exportData method to `void exportDataTo(OutputStream out) throws IOException`.  Don’t store large amounts of data in memory if you don’t have to.